# using ravenDb or mssql as event store

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ravendb, cqrs

I read [Introduction to CQRS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555855/Introduction-to-CQRS) article and I find it very useful.

Code in project which follows this article uses `InMemoryEventStorage` to demonstrate `EventStore` and adding and retrieving events.

I'm aware that this is for demo purposes only but I will like to see on this example how can be built more productive solution using ravenDb or mssql database.

this `InMemoryEventStorage` implements

```
public interface IEventStorage
{
    IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents(Guid aggregateId);
    void Save(AggregateRoot aggregate);
    T GetMemento<T>(Guid aggregateId) where T : BaseMemento;
    void SaveMemento(BaseMemento memento);
}
```

so once more, how could you build ravenDb or mssql db event storage based on example given at link above?

Comment: You can use NEventStore directly. It supports a LOT of dbs and has an in-memory repo .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RavenDB in the normal way - just load and save items through the session:

```
public class RavenEventStorage : IEventStorage
{
    private IDocumentStore store;

    public RavenEventStorage(IDocumentStore store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents(Guid aggregateId)
    {
        using(var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            BaseMemento memento = session.Load<BaseMemento>(aggregateId);

            // Its null if it doesn't exist - so return an empty array
            if(memento==null)
                return new Event[0];

            return memento.Events.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }

    public void Save(AggregateRoot aggregate)
    {
        using(var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(aggregate);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public T GetMemento<T>(Guid aggregateId) where T : BaseMemento
    {
        using(var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Load<T>(aggregateId);
        }
    }

    public void SaveMemento(BaseMemento memento)
    {
        using(var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(memento);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```